# Did Danny Noonan go on to play pro golf?

Tags: plot-explanation, caddyshack

Watched Caddyshack last night and picked up on the conversation between Ty and Danny. Won't repeat the whole thing, but it ends in the lumber yard. Was wondering if after winning the match game and Danny giving up the scholarship, did he decide to skip college and go on to play pro golf?

Comment: Hmmmm...good question!  They never say in the first movie, I don't know if it is even mentioned in the second movie, but I have only seen the second movie one time and one time is one too many :P

Comment: On a related note: http://ftw.usatoday.com/2016/01/somebody-on-reddit-just-destroyed-the-ending-of-caddyshack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Did he decide to skip college and go on to play pro golf?

### We don't know....but yes...and no.

The actual movie (or the "sequel") does not show Danny's story beyond the final tournament and it's resolution.

The scholarship seems to be gone (per [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caddyshack)) but Czervik has offered to recompense him in some fashion (not specified in the movie)

> Czervik promises Danny that he will make it "worth his while" if he wins. Danny eventually decides he would rather humiliate the selfish, conceited Smails than take the scholarship.

However, in a [**earlier draft**](http://www.knowitalljoe.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Caddyshack-Script.pdf) of the script...

Danny arrives home with $24,000 which seems to have been his reward and pay his way through college (which is stated as $8000 a year in the movie).

> ```
>                DANNY (VOICE OVER)
>   Let's see -- uh -- twelve thousand -- an' those are all G-notes...
>   uh so that's twenny-three thousand..twennyfour...I got some quarters here.
> ```

**BUT**

[image]

Later Danny is at the airport with his famility on his way to his original destination college "St Copious of Northen Nebraska" <sup>*</sup>  but when his flight is called he spots a pretty girl in a line for Air Jamaica with a golf bag over her shoulder.

<sup>* Not a real place</sup>

> ```
>  Danny breaks and trots over to the Air Jamaica line
>
>  The PRETTY GIRL is just about to pick up her golf bag
>  when Danny grabs it and slings it easily over his shoulder
>
>                DANNY
>  "Let me show you how it's done"
>
>  They go up the steps together, talking and laughing as they 
>  board the plane
> ```

**SO**, Danny does skip college (at least as far as we know) in favour of enjoying himself but what his future activities are beyond Jamaica we don't know.

Comment: He blew the 24 Gs in Jamaica and now spends his life having to caddy for tourists.  He feels he can't return home because that would mean he failed, so he continues a meager existence where no one ever really gets to know him.  He makes a few friends and is regarded locally as a great golf player, even questioning why he never pursued it further.